# Cleaning code for move generator function for game in c++

Tags: c++, game-development

I am working on my very own chess game in which I need to generate moves for a certain piece on the board. This board is represented in the following format;

```cpp
    int board[8][8];
```

Each number in this board represents a certain piece in the game. Since there are two sides in chess, that is the player white, and player black. I have gotten negative values in this array too.

For example, the White *Bishop* is represented with the integer 2

Therefore, the black one, will be represented with the integer -2

This leaves me with a very simple condition to check whether it's a black or white piece

- If number > 0, the piece is **White**
- If number < 0, the piece is **Black**
- If the number IS 0, there is no piece on the board for that position

Back to the question, Let's assume that I need to generate moves for a pawn

For those of you who do not know the rules of chess, a pawn can move 1 square diagonally if there is an **Opponents** piece on the new square.

I am the White player. Now my condition is;

```cpp
if (number < 0)
```

I am the Black player. Now my condition is;

```cpp
if (number > 0)
```

Do you see the issue? This condition has to be applied for all the pieces and for all the possible positions they can move. Which is a really huge number. The issue is now I have to duplicate my code for the White player, make another function for the black player and paste it in that. And just change that single condition here and there, As **all** other rules of chess are same for both players. Instead of having 6 functions. I will now have 12.

How can I achieve this without having me to Duplicate my code?

My current code uses two seperate functions. I have thought of going through each element in the array and changing the sign  if i generate for black, But that makes it very inefficient

Here is a compilable example, I have tried to keep it as minimal as possible while still giving clarity:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int board[8][8] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
// This board is the chess board and the little one representing the white pawn, and -1:black
std::vector < std::vector <int> > generatemovesPawn_white(int row,int col){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> moves;
    std::vector<int> Move;
    if (board[row-1][col-1] < 0) {
        Move.push_back(row-1);
        Move.push_back(col-1);
        moves.push_back(Move);
    }
    return moves;
}

int main (){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> moves = generatemovesPawn_white(6,1);
    return 1;
}
```

Now, for black all i need is to change the condition from:

```
if (board[row-1][col-1] < 0)
```

to

```
if (board[row-1][col-1] > 0)
```

I hope you see my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract out the condition into a `bool` parameter:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> 
  generatemovesPawn(int row, int col, bool white_or_black)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> moves;
    std::vector<int> Move;
    if (white_or_black) {
        Move.push_back(row-1);
        Move.push_back(col-1);
        moves.push_back(Move);
    }
    return moves;
}
```

and add a level of indirection:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> 
  generatemovesPawn_white(int row, int col)
{
  if (board[row-1][col-1] < 0)
    return generatemovesPawn(row, col, true);
  if (board[row-1][col-1] > 0)
    return generatemovesPawn(row, col, false);
  return {};
}
```

Comment: yeah, right technique, but you probably want the black pawns moving in the opposite direction :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey That's possible, but OP explicitly says that this is the *only* line they need to change, so that's what I did :p

Comment: I'm looking for a way I wouldn't have to repeat my code, this way still repeats my code as snippet row-1 col-1 is only one condition whereas truly there are 20-30 total and all those have to be copied to the other clause

Comment: As you see in your code you have also copied the same statement chaning "<" and ">"

Comment: @AryanParekh Yes, this answer may not work exactly as you want, but it's only showing the technique. Anyway, I strongly suggest asking this on code review. You'll get better feedback there for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Okay, One way i mentioned it would be possible is making all numbers which are negative, positive, and vice versa This way I apply only one block of code for white, and for black i apply the same thing without repeating just changing the numbers, but this makes it slower and repeating the code start's to make more sense 

Comment: @AryanParekh Yes, that sounds like a reasonable approach as well. If you refactor it *well* then it should end up more readable. This can take practice, and some trial by error, till you find a good solution.

Comment: Since you are way more experienced than me, I wanted to ask you, In Your way although it repeats the code, it is much easier to read and write. Should i still avoid it?

Comment: This can actually be quite subjective, and depends a lot on the code that is being refactored. Also, different people may find different solutions more or less readable. I suggest trying out various approaches, and slowly developing a feeling for what feels right. This won't happen overnight, so be patient :) And write the same code lots of different ways :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :). It just scares me to know that I will get negative comments when people look at my code.

Comment: Haha, yeah that can be scary, but nothing ventured, nothing gained. At least if you try, you'll learn something, even if it's how *not* to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Add a bool that states if it's white or black to the function arguments, and add an if statement to check the bool

```
std::vector < std::vector <int> > generatemovesPawn(int row,int col, bool wb)
{
//...


    if (wb && board[row-1][col-1] < 0)
    {
        //... do white stuff
    }
    else if (!wb && board[row-1][col-1] > 0)
    {
        //... do black stuff
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: This one is as good as using another function, as instead of explicitly mentionion generate moves black or white, i put it in a parameter of the same function where it then checks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your code dependant on a variable, as opposed to hardcoding a colour.

For example, without trying it, I changed your code, below. It takes a colour and adjusts its behaviour based on the colour. It uses a variable dx,dy to store the direction pawns of each colour move.

```
// This board is the chess board and the little one representing the white pawn, and -1:black

std::vector < std::vector <int> > generatemovesPawn(int row, int col, bool whiteToPlay)
{
    int dx = -1;
    int dy = whiteToPlay ? 1 : -1;
    int pawnId = whiteToPlay ? 1 : -1;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> moves;
    std::vector<int> Move;
    if (board[row + dx][col + dy] == pawnId) 
    {
        Move.push_back(row + dx);
        Move.push_back(col + dy);
        moves.push_back(Move);
    }
    return moves;
 }
```

But my original suggestion holds: ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com . This is the right place for these questions.